OKE node pool stuck in "Deleting" state
There is some option to force delete the node pool?
It's about 24h in Deleting state and not deleted yet.
How delete it?
Terminating the nodes in pool are not help.
The second request via cli or web is with zero "Force terminate after grace period" are not executing due Conflict: The state for this resource is invalid for the operation being requested.
